# Neuroph: Multi Layer Perceptron Backpropagation learning not working

Tags: java, neural-network

This question is related to [Neuroph](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/) Java library.

I have the following program which creates a multi layer perceptron containing a single hidden layer of 20 nodes. The function being learnt is x^2. Backpropagation learning rule is used. However, as is evident from the output, the program doesn't seem to work. The output is always 1. Is there any error in my program?

Program

```
import org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork;
import org.neuroph.core.data.DataSet;
import org.neuroph.nnet.MultiLayerPerceptron;
import org.neuroph.nnet.learning.BackPropagation;
import org.neuroph.util.TransferFunctionType;

public class SquareNeuralNetwork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = new MultiLayerPerceptron(TransferFunctionType.SIGMOID, 1, 20, 1);
        DataSet trainingSet = new DataSet(1, 1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            trainingSet.addRow(new double[]{i}, new double[]{i * i});
        }
        BackPropagation backPropagation = new BackPropagation();
        backPropagation.setMaxIterations(10);
        neuralNetwork.learn(trainingSet, backPropagation);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            neuralNetwork.setInput(i);
            neuralNetwork.calculate();
            double output = neuralNetwork.getOutput()[0];
            System.out.println(i + " - " + output);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 - 1.0
2 - 1.0
3 - 1.0
4 - 1.0
5 - 1.0
6 - 1.0
7 - 1.0
8 - 1.0
9 - 1.0
10 - 1.0
11 - 1.0
12 - 1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The sigmoid

The sigmoid activation function output values in the range:

[image]

It seems that you are trying to teach the sigmoid function to output values from 1 to 10000, which is impossible. The best fitness the network can achieve is thus to always output 1's.

[image]

## Alternative approach

You can still teach the neural network to model the exponential function if you remodel the function to 1/x^2 rather than x^2, since this will modify the output range to [0, 1] for x >= 1. When using the network after the training has completed, you have to divide 1 / output in order to get the exponential curve you intended.

I modelled a network with 20 hidden nodes and one hidden layer as a proof of concept :

[image]

Comment: It's been a long time since I did backprop, but doesn't the library provide a way to generate outputs outside of [0,1]^n? For example if an output unit is just the weighted sum of the fan-in (sigmoid on the hidden units but *not* on the outputs) then we should be able to learn the original, nonnormalized function...

Comment: You could use the linear function of course - but it is not uncommon to squash or project the target function into the [1, 0] range. The linear function is not bounded, neither is the popular Rectified linear function ReLU.